# Security issues when logging in to facebook from android webview

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview, facebook-login

I want to load some facebook links in android webview. But it requires users to **login to facebook through that webview** before they can reach to actual content. After that login, webview everytime uses its cookies so that no further login is required and users can see the contents without any interruption.

My question is, since the users will login from the webview directly, will they feel unsecured regarding their facebook credentials? Is it possible for the developer to capture their credentials from that app? If yes, in what process it can be made more reliable to users?

Comment: A webview isn’t that much different from a “normal” browser in that regard, other apps can not just interfere with it willy-nilly and grab stuff like login credentials typed into forms on the site opened …

Comment: @CBroe since webview does not show urls, how will users know that they are giving their credentials to the webview and not in my app? how will they be confirmed that its not a phishing attempt?

Comment: Ah ok, now I get your point. Starting pointsd for further lecture could be https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25917/are-web-views-in-android-secure, and https://9to5mac.com/2014/09/24/app-developer-warns-not-to-enter-personal-info-using-in-app-browsers-due-to-security-issue/

Comment: @CBroe according to above articles, typing facebook passwords in a 3rd party app webview is not secured because of phishing or keystrokes capture. is there any way by which I can convince the users that the webview is not a phishing and their keystrokes are not being captured?